# How to fix Pause delay in Workflow

Tags: workflow, pause

I am Usign 'pause' in Workflow with Sharepoint 2010
and I want to pause my Workflow for 1 minute:

[image]

But this 1 minute has a delay of 5 minutes...
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try to change it to 0.2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pause in Workflow is used by SharePoint Timer Job, when the timer job runs, the workflow run.

The default time is 5 minutes. So If something starts at 15:02, at 15:05 the timer job will process. Note that this time can be extended if the timer job cannot complete all the tasks. Eg. 15:02 starts, but only at 15:10 timer job can complete the request to "unpause" the workflow.

You can change in CA the timer job processing time, but you should know that maybe in 1 minute is not enough to process everything.

(Monitoring > Timer Job > Job Definitions > Job Title: Workflow)
[image]

Comment: I cant find this option(Monitoring ) in my settings... how can I find it?

Comment: It's in central admin.  Do you have access to that?

Comment: Here is SharePoint 2013, but in Central Administration it is the same menus of 2010: http://i60.tinypic.com/i1bnra.png